# Google maps markers with javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am building an application that has a database of people's names, info about them and their current location. 
I managed to create a maps using Google maps javascript API, and mark your current location. however, i cant seem to be able to use a PHP loop to place a marker with an info window for every person in my database. Here is my code:

```
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
lon = position.coords.longitude;

//init map
myOptions = {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
   zoom: 15,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var image = 'http://i43.tinypic.com/v48d1w.png';
var loca = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
var currnetLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: loca,
map: map,
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
icon: image
});
var contentString;
var marklatlng;
<?php
require("connect.php");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gigs");
$i = 0;
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "
contentString = 'Name: <b>" . $data['name'] . "</b><br> Info: <b>" . $data['desc'] . "    </b>';
var infowindow" . $i . " = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString
});
marklatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(" . $data['lat'] . ", " . $data['lng'] . ");
var marker" . $i . " = new google.maps.Marker({
position: markLatlng,
map: map,
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker" . $i . ", 'click', function() {
infowindow" . $i . ".open(map,marker" . $i . ");
});

";
$i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would  be better to json_encode your data, pass that to a variable in javascript, and then loop over it using javascript. Even better would be using AJAX requests to fetch the data.

```
<?php
function fetchGigs() {
  $gigs = new Array();
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gigs");
  while($gig = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $gigs[] = $gig; 
  }
  return $gigs;
}
```

And in your javascript:

```
<script>
// your other code...
var gigs = <?php echo json_encode(fetchGigs()); ?>

var createMarkerAt = function(lat, lng) {
  var latLng, marker;
  latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
  });
  return marker;
}

var createMarkerForGig = function (gig) {
  var marker, info;
  marker = createMarkerAt(gig.lat, gig.lng);
  info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Name: <b>"' + gig.name + '"</b><br>Info: <b>"' + gig.desc + '"</b>'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    info.open(map, marker);
  });
  return marker;
}

// Add markers for all the gigs.
var len = gigs.length;
for (var i = 0; i<len; i++) {
  createMarkerForGig(gigs[i]);
}
</script>
```

[Documentation for `php_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Sorry, im not very familiar with javascript. can you give me a code example please?

Comment: Working on it, but if your going to try this with a big table and without ajax, you're going to get a very slow website..

Comment: That should work. But I seriously recommend using AJAX and PDO instead of `mysql_query` stuff.

Comment: For some reason this does not work, it gives back a white screen.. maybe a problem in the loop?

Comment: Any errors you can see? Make sure to turn on error_reporting in php (`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: I think you missed the $i variable in the PHP loop, ill look if its that.

Comment: The $i is not important I put it in by accident when copy pasting from your code..

Comment: Nope, not that. i still get a white screen. And i cant open the error report since its on a collaborative code platform. do you see anything wrong?

Comment: I'm not going to write your whole script :/ And I can't help you if you can't even tell me about the errors.

Comment: Its not any PHP error, your php code works. i think something is wrong with the javascript, and for some reason the loop is not working. It is also terminating the whole page, so i get a white blank page.

Comment: I did just edit this though `var gig = gigs[i];` make sure it says `gigs`.

Comment: Use your browsers `console` to debug javascript.

Comment: Looking in the console, i get some very stuff.. its acting as if the code doesn't even exist. have a look at: arielschon12.kodingen.com

Comment: It's doable, I made something very similar. I'm putting it back online  write now, should be ready in an hour ( have to fix some server stuff). You can look at the javascript if you want.

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote a similar application I used php to write the string of a javascript array representing my data and then used straight js once i got to building strings for the api.  However, since I have discovered how easy it is to write a PHP powered API to return JSON objects of my database I just use jQuery to query my homebrew API for the json data and then work with that.  It truly is incredibly easy to do with SLIM.  Here is a link http://codingthis.com/programming/php/using-the-slim-php-framework-for-developing-rest-apis/

Comment: Sorry, i just didn't get what you are talking about. I just want to loop some javascript code over and over again untill i did it for every piece of data in my db.